# Uniformly integrability and convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-integrability

**Question 1**: $X_n$'s are **non-negative, uniformly integrable**. Then $E\left[\dfrac{\max_{1\leq k \leq n} X_k}{n}\right]\rightarrow 0$.

**Question 2**: If **u.i.** is dropped then the above may fail.

**My thought**: If I can show $\dfrac{\max_{1\leq k \leq n} X_k}{n}$ is *u.i.* as well as *converges in probability to $0$* then I am done. Probably I am not thinking in the right direction. Any kind of help/hint is what I am looking for and will appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: You're leaving out some hypotheses - saying $X_n=1$ gives a counterexample to the question as stated.

Comment: @David: No it doesn't: you get 1/n.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I did not understand. If $X_n=1$ w.p. 1 then the expectation also goes to 0. Does not it?

Comment: Hint for question 2: if you choose the $X_n$ to have disjoint supports, then the max equals the sum. You can even take $EX_n =1$ for all n, showing that uniform integrability is not the same as "uniformly bounded in mean".

Comment: Thanks @Nate. I've done similar problem where $X_n$'s were identical $L_1$(that situation were simpler). But Question 1 I am not able to crack.

Comment: There are a couple of equivalent definitions of "uniformly integrable". Which one(s) do you know?

Comment: $\lim_{c\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{n\geq1} E(|X_n|I_{|X_n|>c})=0$

Comment: Sorry, read it wrong.

Comment: @NateEldredge However if  I don't know something that is crucial in your answer I'll look up in the internet/books as I always appreciate new things/learning. I think the question is almost surely correct. I doubted at first sight but then cross-checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You can prove it directly, without the Vitali convergence theorem.

A hint to get you started:

Let's let $M_n = \max_{1 \le k \le n} X_k$.  Now fix $\epsilon > 0$ and write
$$E\left[\frac{M_n}{n}\right] \le E\left[\frac{M_n}{n}; M_n \le \epsilon n\right] + \sum_{k=1}^n E\left[\frac{M_n}{n}; M_n > \epsilon n, M_n = X_k\right].$$
(The inequality is to handle the possibility of a "tie", when $M_n = X_k$ for  more than one $k$, so that the events $\{M_n = X_k\}, k=1,\dots,n$ are not disjoint.)

Q2: As in my comment, if you choose the $X_k$ to have disjoint support, then $M_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$.  Now choose them such that $E[X_k] = 1$ for every $k$.  (You can construct such a sequence on the probability space $[0,1]$ equipped with Lebesgue measure...)